# php time ago function

Tags: php, time, timestamp, timeago

I just need a tip for a function that shows the time in ago format.
On my database I have time stroed as timestamp. There are comments from users with date as timestamp. This date need to convert in time ago. I have a function but can't be recalled for every comment. It is working only 1 time for 1 comment. Can somebody help?

this is my function

```
function humanTiming($time)
{

$time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
$time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
$tokens = array (
    31536000 => 'year',
    2592000 => 'month',
    604800 => 'week',
    86400 => 'day',
    3600 => 'hour',
    60 => 'minute',
    1 => 'second'
);

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
}

}
```

Comment: Are you converting the timestamp to epoch before passing it to `humanTiming()`

Comment: No, i do not @DanielSmith

Comment: Yes you right @GautamKrishnaR but that function can not be redeclared for 2 comments for example.

Comment: Why are you redeclaring? Is the method definition inside your loop?

Comment: If you have composer in your project you can import [carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), then use their 'diffForHumans()' function and you'll have it.

Comment: @DanielSmith No is not. I call the function one time after the comment from database. Normaly should show the comment then the date (database date is timestamp format) converted in time ago format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate, but closing it won't show you what the problem in your code is.

The [`return` statement](http://php.net/return) will immediately return the passed value from the function, and end execution of the function. So you will not ever get past the first run of your `foreach` loop. Probably what you want to do is something like this, where you build a string up in the loop, and then return it:

```
$ret = "";
foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
    if ($time < $unit) continue;
    $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
    $ret .= $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
}
return $ret;
```

I didn't actually check if your code would work, but this is the crux of your problem.